# Amazon OpsWorks: Automating server startup

Tags: amazon-web-services

Using Amazon OpsWorks, is it possible to auto up and down a linux server, say for example
from 4.30pm to 5.30pm ?

Answer (score 1):

Look at time based instances: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/workinginstances-autoscaling.html